# how to use arrays in methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Every time I try running this I get a java exception code. Any Ideas?

```
package employ;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employ {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String []empna={};

     int numofemp;
     int []empnu;
     String []empadd;
     int []emphd;
     //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("how many employees do you have?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        numofemp=sc.nextInt();
        for (int j=0;j<numofemp;j++){

        empnam (empna,j);
           // System.out.println(empna[0]);
        }
    }

     public static void  empnam(String empna[], int j ){
         System.out.println("What is your employees first and last name?");
         Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        //String ns=n.nextLine();
        empna[j]=n.nextLine();


    }

}
```

Comment: Which exception on which line?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't initialize the array with the correct size, this line is wrong:

```
String []empna={};
```

Try this instead, right after the line where you read the value of `numofemp`:

```
String[] empna = new String[numofemp];
```

Remember, an array in Java is of fixed length and its size must be specified at the creation time, it won't grow as elements are being added to it. If a variable-length array were needed, then use an `ArrayList`.